# github actions self-hosted runner stuck on authentication--linux ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I am trying to configure a github runner on my ubuntu server but it seems to be stuck on the authetnication step when I try to configure it (./config --url --token.)  I have opened up port 443 and 80 and 22 and it still doesn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3odMU.jpg)

Comment: What is the version of runner? Is this running on VM, container or bare-metal? Also, please follow community guidelines and post text instead of image links.